# unexpected token, identifier expected

Tags: java

Что я пропустил в коде?

`mp = MediaPlayer.create(namaz.this, R.raw.(funkc(trackID)));` - выбивает unexpected token, identifier expected.

В  `public int funkc (int track_id_get)`  выдает - missing return statement

в гугле смотрел.

```
public int funkc (int track_id_get) {
        switch (track_id_get) {
            case 1:
                return 1;
                break;
            case2:
                return 2;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

void playStop(int stop, int play, int trackID)
    {
        if(stop == 1)
        {
            stopPlaying();
        }
        else
        if (play == 1)
        {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(namaz.this, R.raw.(funkc(trackID))); // vizovFunccii(track_id - это номер трека, который нужно воспроизвести))
            mp.start();

    }
    }
```

Comment: Это так `R.raw.(funkc(trackID))` не работает. Тут параметром ожидается целое число, а у вас передается какой-то странный вызов непонятно чего на `R.raw`

Comment: Для начала опечатка здесь - ``case2:``. Не хватает пробела. Во-вторых, такая функция funkc, как она сейчас выглядит, вообще не нужна. В-третьих, см. предыдущий комментарий. Из ``R.raw.(funkc(trackID))`` не получится ни R.raw.1, ни R.raw.2 (похоже, что вы хотите достичь именно этого).

Comment: @rjhdby , я этой функцией пытаюсь подставить имя трека из папки raw.У меня их 11.И чтобы для каждого не создавать.

Comment: @Эникейщик , не подскажите как мне тогда организовать все это иначе?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `R.*` - это константы. Нельзя их использовать генерируя имена в рантайме.

Должно быть как-то так

```
public int funkc (int track_id_get) {
    switch (track_id_get) {
        case 1:
            return R.raw.1;
        case 2:
            return R.raw.2;
        default:
            return R.raw.default;
    }
}
```

И потом

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(namaz.this, funkc(trackID));
```

2) В случае, если в вашу функцию `funk` передать, например, `3`, то что она вернет? В вашем случае `return` вообще не будет достугнут.

Всегда, когда используете `return` внутри `swith`, у вас должен быть вариант возврата значения из блока `default` (если, конечно, у вас там не `ENUM` перебирается полностью)

3) Также, если в `case` используется `return`, то `breake` не обязателен - выполнение программы до него просто никогда не дойдет

Comment: Ругается на имена (R.raw.1;) not a statement
; expected

Comment: @AdamChe тут два варианта, либо тут опечатка и точка с запятой лишняя, либо вы неверные идентификаторы используете и `R.raw.1` действительно отсутствует

Comment: вы совершенно правы, имя ресурса поменял и все.Но вылезла другая ошибка, ругается на break; - unreachable statement .

Comment: @AdamChe не ругается, а предупреждает. Действительно, если у вас в `case` стоит `return`, то `break` там не нужен - выполнение до него никогда не дойдет. Добавлю в ответ

Comment: огромное вам спасибо .